# Problems with multiple joins in SQL Server - advice please

Tags: sql-server

This is my T-SQL query:

```
SELECT  
    debt_trans_1.debt_code, debt_trans_1.tx_amount AS new_amount, 
    debt_trans.tx_amount, debt_trans.packetid, 
    debt_trans.debt_code AS master_code, debt_trans_2.tx_amount AS rev, 
    debt_trans.tx_date
FROM
    debt_trans 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    instplan ON debt_trans.packetid = instplan.packetid 
             AND debt_trans.tran_code = instplan.tran_code 
             AND debt_trans.debt_code = instplan.debt_code 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    debt_trans AS debt_trans_2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    debt_trans AS debt_trans_1 ON debt_trans_2.tx_seq = debt_trans_1.tx_seq + 1 
                               AND debt_trans_2.tx_time = debt_trans_1.tx_time 
                               AND debt_trans_2.tx_date = debt_trans_1.tx_date 
                               AND debt_trans_2.debt_code = debt_trans_1.debt_code 
      ON debt_trans.packetid = debt_trans_1.packetid 
        AND debt_trans.tran_code = debt_trans_1.tran_code 
        AND debt_trans.tx_date = debt_trans_1.tx_date 
        AND debt_trans.tx_time = debt_trans_1.tx_time
WHERE        
    (debt_trans.debt_code IN ('MASKEDCODE02', 'MASKEDCODE01')) 
    AND (debt_trans.tx_date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-19') 
    AND (debt_trans.tran_code = 'DR3015')
ORDER BY 
    debt_trans_1.debt_code
```

Output

```
debt_code   new_amount  tx_amount   packetid    master_code rev tx_date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MASKEDCODEA2    60.00   60.00   3903375 MASKEDCODE02    8.10    2019-02-04 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEA2    60.00   60.00   3903375 MASKEDCODE02    8.10    2019-02-04 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEA2    10.39   10.39   3903375 MASKEDCODE02    1.40    2019-02-04 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEA2    10.39   10.39   3903375 MASKEDCODE02    1.40    2019-02-04 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEA1    255.37  379.67  3736780 MASKEDCODE01    39.58   2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEB1    310.60  379.67  3736780 MASKEDCODE01    48.14   2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEC1    379.67  379.67  3736780 MASKEDCODE01    58.85   2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

You will see I have duplicate entries in here. I know I can use the `DISTINCT` option in there. But is they another way of reducing this, because after this I need to join more tables to this. And if I do it now I get loads more entries.

Ideally it should only output 5 records.

```
debt_code   new_amount  tx_amount   packetid    master_code rev tx_date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MASKEDCODEA2    10.39   10.39   3903375 MASKEDCODE02    1.40    2019-02-04 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEA2    60.00   60.00   3903375 MASKEDCODE02    8.10    2019-02-04 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEA1    255.37  379.67  3736780 MASKEDCODE01    39.58   2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEB1    310.60  379.67  3736780 MASKEDCODE01    48.14   2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
MASKEDCODEC1    379.67  379.67  3736780 MASKEDCODE01    58.85   2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**: my guess at what your query really looks like.

```
SELECT  debt_trans_1.debt_code
    , debt_trans_1.tx_amount AS new_amount
    , debt_trans.tx_amount
    , debt_trans.packetid
    , debt_trans.debt_code AS master_code
    , debt_trans_2.tx_amount AS rev
    , debt_trans.tx_date
FROM debt_trans 
LEFT OUTER JOIN instplan ON debt_trans.packetid = instplan.packetid 
                        AND debt_trans.tran_code = instplan.tran_code 
                        AND debt_trans.debt_code = instplan.debt_code 

LEFT OUTER JOIN debt_trans AS debt_trans_1 ON debt_trans.packetid = debt_trans_1.packetid 
                                            AND debt_trans.tran_code = debt_trans_1.tran_code 
                                            AND debt_trans.tx_date = debt_trans_1.tx_date 
                                            AND debt_trans.tx_time = debt_trans_1.tx_time
FULL OUTER JOIN debt_trans AS debt_trans_2 ON debt_trans_2.tx_seq = debt_trans_1.tx_seq + 1 
                                        AND debt_trans_2.tx_time = debt_trans_1.tx_time 
                                        AND debt_trans_2.tx_date = debt_trans_1.tx_date 
                                        AND debt_trans_2.debt_code = debt_trans_1.debt_code 
WHERE debt_trans.debt_code IN ('MASKEDCODE02', 'MASKEDCODE01')
    AND debt_trans.tx_date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-19'
    AND debt_trans.tran_code = 'DR3015'
ORDER BY debt_trans_1.debt_code
```

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read that.  Also, do tell what you are trying to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I took a guess at what your query might actually be. As posted, there is no chance that is your query because it would have failed with syntax errors. Also, be very careful here. You are using **between** with what may very likely be datetime columns. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: For a solid answer you need to provide some details. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The query runs actually ok. as its build in the Query Designer on MS SQL Management Studio

Comment: Looked at the between bit and it seems to be the bit that is creating it to mess up.

Thank you Sean Lange

Comment: The simple solution is to place a DISTINCT in your query. now the duplicity is caused by the JOIN you have, I recommend that you go through each of it and evaluate why this is caused.

Comment: The problem is most-likely because you are not filtering enough.  Your `WHERE` clause has 3 columns that you are filtering in `debt_trans`, but your joined tables don't have the same filters. That could produce a cartesian product (like you are seeing). I usually confirm this by (temporarily) selecting all of the columns from `debt_trans_1` and `debt_trans_2`.  I'd wager that `debt_trans_1.debt_code`, `debt_trans_2.debt_code` or `debt_trans_.tran_code`, `debt_trans_2.tran_code` need filters too.